# What does "Unexpected precompiled header error" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

I was trying to build a simple solution involving a Windows and a Console application. After using the wizard to generate the code skeleton for the projects, I didn't add any code and just built the generated code. In both cases I got the same error:

`1>c:\c\winpr\winpr\winpr.cpp(4) : fatal error C1859: 'Debug\winpr.pch' unexpected precompiled header error, simply rerunning the compiler might fix this problem`

What is wrong, any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried rerunning the compiler as the error message suggests?

Comment: Show us your source, specifically the top of the .cpp file where the `#include` statements are.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a fix for Visual C++ 2008 SP1 compiler error C1859. You may download it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=25785).

For details see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/12/visual-c-precompiled-header-errors-on-windows-7.aspx).

Comment: The fix at the link provided works and is still available as of today.  This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: This update failed to install the first time on my system, it worked the second time though (rerunning it with windows check for correct installation termination)

Comment: Been using VS 2008 for 5 years and never got this problem before. I couldn't build anything no matter what I did. The patch fixed it.

Comment: Sadly the patch no longer appears to be available

Comment: Search for `VS90SP1-KB976656-x86.exe` found me [this link](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?autocom=downloads&showfile=11640)

Comment: Yes, that link provided by @JacobSeleznev appears to have fixed this issue. Note that although the file is not hosted on Microsoft servers, it still has a valid Microsoft digital signature, so we can assume that it is safe to install. Also as an additional comment, this issue seems to be connected to Windows Updates. Every time you see that "nuisance" popup during the middle of your workday urging you to install Windows updates, this issue is somehow connected to it. So restarting the box may also resolve the issue.

Comment: We're using Visual Studio 2010 and seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

We had something similar at work all of a sudden, one day. Our problem was down to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/12/visual-c-precompiled-header-errors-on-windows-7.aspx)

A simple PC restart done it for me anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The link provided in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854569/1998471) is **no longer available**.

I was getting the same error and in my case the problem was due to a '**Windows Update**' that required a restart (which I **avoided** the **restart** and kept getting this problem). But after the reboot the error was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Installing visual C++ 2008 SP1 fixed my issue.

Comment: As it did for me since the previously posted patch is dead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install this patch (KB976656 - Error message when you use the Visual C++ 2008 compiler: "fatal error C1859") to fix this issue:

http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?autocom=downloads&showfile=11640

Comment: 2019 - Only thehotfixshare has it.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score -6):

If you have `#include<stdfafx.h>`, try commenting it out like so `//#include<stdfafx.h>` as it may be the culprit behind your errors.

Comment: This is definitely a bad idea.